# website not working in linode

Tags: php, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, linode

i got the new hosting plan on Linode and i have installed ubuntu 10.04 LTS on it and i have hosted my website on it. i have made my website in codeigniter, But the links in linode are not working i have uploaded my website on some other hosting and it is working properly but on linode it is not navigating from one page to another page.I dont know what the issue is.

this is the code of my htascess file-->

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Please any one help me out.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 'linode' has nothing to do with it, a linode is a VPS, YOU have to configure apache or whatever web server you setup by yourself.  Look at their great guides if you have trouble, this is not the right place to ask this question (notice the CLOSE requests pending on it).

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your htaccess that I can see is that the lines that say this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Should read:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Hopefully that fixes it.

You can see the suggested content here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html